# Show that two processes have the same distribution knowing that their paths up to time $τ$ and their distributions conditioned on $\mathcal F_τ$ agree

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process, conditional-probability

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(E,\mathcal E)$ be a measurable space
- $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ and $(\tilde Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be time-homogeneous Markov chains on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $\kappa$ denote the transition kernel of $Y$
- $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a filtration on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ to which $\tilde Y$ is adapted
- $\tau$ be an $\mathcal F$-stopping time with $$1_{\left\{\:n\:<\:\tau\:\right\}}Y_n=1_{\left\{\:n\:<\:\tau\:\right\}}\tilde Y_n\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N_0$$ and$^1$$^2$ $$\operatorname P\left[\tau<\infty,\left(\tilde Y_{\tau+n_1},\ldots,\tilde Y_{\tau+n_k}\right)\mid\mathcal F_\tau\right]=1_{\left\{\:\tau\:<\:\infty\:\right\}}\bigotimes_{i=1}^k\kappa^{n_i-n_{i-1}}(Y_\tau,B)\tag1$$ almost surely for all $k\in\mathbb N_0$, $n_0,\ldots,n_k\in\mathbb N_0$ with $0=n_0<\cdots<n_k$ and $B\in\mathcal E^{\otimes k}$

> Are we able to conclude that $Y$ and $\tilde Y$ have the same distribution?

It's clear to me that the distribution is uniquely determined by the finite-dimensional distributions. For simplicity and as a first step, I've tried to prove $$\operatorname P\left[Y_n\in B\right]=\operatorname P\left[\tilde Y_n\in B\right]\tag2$$ for some fixed $n\in\mathbb N_0$ and $B\in\mathcal E$. My idea is to write $$\operatorname P\left[\tilde Y\in B\right]=\operatorname P\left[n<\tau,\tilde Y\in B\right]+\operatorname P\left[n\ge\tau,\tilde Y\in B\right].\tag3$$ By $(1)$, it's sufficient to show the second term on the right-hand side of $(3)$ is equal to $\operatorname P\left[n\ge\tau,Y\in B\right]$ in order to conclude $(2)$. Noting that $\left\{n\ge\tau\right\}=\biguplus_{m=0}^n\left\{\tau=m\right\}$, we obtain \begin{equation}\begin{split}\operatorname P\left[n\ge\tau,\tilde Y\in B\right]&=\sum_{m=0}^n\operatorname P\left[\tau=m,\tilde Y_{\tau+(n-m)}\in B\right]\\&=\sum_{m=0}^n\operatorname E\left[1_{\left\{\:\tau\:=\:m\:\right\}}\kappa^{n-m}(Y_\tau,B)\right]\\&=\operatorname E\left[1_{\left\{\:n\:\ge\:\tau\:\right\}}\kappa^{n-\tau}(Y_\tau,B)\right]\end{split}\tag4\end{equation} by $(1)$.

> However, I don't know how to conclude $(2)$ from $(4)$. And I don't see how this approach can be generalized in order to show the actual claim.

(By the way, I would be interested in a solution which would still work if the index set $\mathbb N_0$ is replaced by something uncountable like $[0,\infty)$ - but that's not mandatory; if you only know a solution for the countable case that would be fine for me).

---

$^1$ $\mathcal F_\tau$ denotes the [$\sigma$-algebra of $\tau$-past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-Algebra_of_%CF%84-past#Definition).

$^2$ $\bigotimes$ denotes the [product of transition kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel#Product_of_kernels).

Comment: Doesn't give the strong Markov property of $Y$ immediately that the last term in (4) equals $P(n \geq \tau, Y \in B)$....?

Comment: @saz But why should $Y$ be strongly Markovian at $\tau$? $\tau$ is an $\mathcal F$-stopping time, but $Y$ is not adapted to $\mathcal F$. (In my actual application $\mathcal F_n=\sigma(X_0,\ldots,X_n)\vee\sigma(Y_0,\ldots,Y_n))$ where $X$ is a process which is independent of $Y$; maybe that's helping out?)

Comment: I see; I missed that $Y$ doesn't need to be adapted to $\mathcal{F}$. If $\mathcal{F}_n$ is defined as you wrote, then $\mathcal{F}_n \supseteq \sigma(Y_0,\ldots,Y_n)$ which would mean that $Y$ is adapted to $\mathcal{F}$... or not? (I'm interpreting your notation $\mathcal{A} \vee \mathcal{B}$ as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$... )

Comment: @saz Sorry, I didn't intend to write about adaptedness, but Markovianess. $Y$ is Markovian with respect to its generated filtration, but not wrt $\mathcal F$. However, the special shape of $\mathcal F$ might help out?

Comment: Yes, $Y$ is Markovian with respect to the augmented filtration $\mathcal{F}$. You can use the following property of conditional expectation to prove this: If $Z$ is a random variable with is measurable with respect to a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{H}$,$\mathcal{G}$ are further $\sigma$-algebras satisfying $$\mathcal{H} \, \, \text{is independent of} \, \, \sigma(\sigma(Z),\mathcal{G})$$ then $$\mathbb{E}(Z \mid \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})) = \mathbb{E}(Z \mid \mathcal{G}).$$

Comment: Okay, thank you. How do we need to generalize the idea behind $(3)$ in order to show that all finite-dimensional distributions agree?

Comment: The finite dimensional distributions of a Markov chain $Y$ are uniquely determined by the distribution of $Y_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. To show this, you can write $\mathbb{P}(Y_1 \in B_1,\ldots,Y_n \in B_n)$ as an iterated integral using the Markov property.

Comment: @saz You're using that the distribution is uniquely determined by the transition kernel, right? That argument works only in the time-homogeneous, discrete time case. What would we need to do, if the index set is $[0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, you could put it like that... .but also in the time-continuous case the finite dimensional distributions of a Markov process are uniquely determined by the one-dimensional distributions $P_{Y_t}$, $t \geq 0$.

Comment: @saz Hm, if $(X_t)_{t\in I}$ is a Markov process with transition semigroup $(\kappa_{s,\:t}:s\le t)$, then $$\operatorname P\left[X_{t_0}\in B_1,\ldots,X_{t_n}\in B_n\right]=\int\operatorname P\left[X_{t_0}\in{\rm d}x_0\right]\int_{B_1}\kappa_{t_0,\:t_1}(x_0,{\rm d}x_1)\cdots\int_{B_n}\kappa_{t_{n-1},\:t_n}(x_{n-1},{\rm d}x_n)\tag5$$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, $t_0,\ldots,t_n\in I$ with $t_0\le\cdots\le t_n$ and $B_1,\ldots,B_n\in\mathcal E$. So, $(5)$ depends on the distribution of $X_{t_0}$ *and* all the $\kappa_{t_i,\:t_{i-1}}$. What am I missing?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake; I thought we were still talking about the time-homogeneous case.

Comment: @saz Feel free to assume time-homogeneity. In that case, $\kappa_{t_i,\:t_{i-1}}=\kappa_{t_i-t_{i-1}}$. How does that help (unless I is countable)?

Comment: Help to do what exactly? I got lost somewhere, I think. I was just saying that the fdd's are uniquely determined by $\kappa$.

Comment: @saz You've said that the fdds are uniquely determined by the one-dimensional distributions. And I don't think that this is true, even in the time-homogeneous case, when the index set is $[0,\infty)$. In any case, the actual question was how we can prove the claim in the question, using the idea behind $(3)$, if the index set is $[0,\infty)$ (and the Markov processes are still time-homogeneous).

Comment: @saz By the way: The motivation for the question stems from [my coupling question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3068439/find-a-modified-coupling-x-n-tilde-y-n-n%e2%88%88%e2%84%95-0-with-the-same-coupling-tim). I've assumed in this question that $\tilde Y$ is Markov, but it's not clear to me why the special $\tilde Y$ from that other question is Markov. Maybe you can take a quick look.

Comment: For time-continuous processes, one needs a particular form of the strong Markov property which states that $$\mathbb{E}(f(Y_{\eta}) \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau})(\omega) = \int f(y) \, \kappa_{\eta(\omega)-\tau(\omega)}(Y_{\tau}(\omega),dy)$$ where $\tau \leq \eta$ are stopping times... this holds for "nice" time-cts. Markov processes; for BM you can find a proof in the book by Schilling & Partzsch (Theorem 6.11). Using this result, you can show that the first expression in (4) equals the last expression in (4).

Comment: @saz Is being Feller "nice" enough? Do you have any reference of a more general result (more general than only for BM)? But as a first question: Why is an expression of the $\kappa_\tau$ measurable? (That was easily seen in the countable case, but in the continuous case ...)

Comment: Ah, sorry, I forgot to one assumption: it is assumed that $\eta \geq \tau$ is $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$-measurable (resp. $\mathcal{F}_{\tau+}$-measurable if we replace $\mathcal{F}_{\tau}$ by $\mathcal{F}_{\tau+}$ on the left-hand side of the equation in my previous comment). And yes, Feller is nice enough. From the proof in Schillings book you can see that you need essentially the strong Markov property and right contiuity of the sample paths.